# PHP xpath to extract value from webpage of a specific ID

Tags: php, xpath

I need some assistance with xpath to extract a value $283 out of an html page.

Here's my PHP

```
$html = file_get_contents("https://test.com/testpage.php");
$html = tidy_repair_string($html);
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);

$avg = $xpath->evaluate('string(//*[@id="Average"]/@value)');
echo $avg;
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="List">
    <span class="bold">Avg</span> 
    <span id="Average">$283</span>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this XPath expression :

```
//div[@class="List"]/span[@id="Average"]
```

or simply :

```
//*[@id='Average']
```

This is a full working code :

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://127.0.0.1/test.html');

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$elements = $xpath->query("//*[@id='Average']");

if (!is_null($elements)) {
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $nodes = $element->childNodes;
        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
            echo $node->nodeValue. "\n";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Just replace URL with your own.

Comment: how to use this to extract data from a div having certain class ?

Comment: `div[@class="foobar"]`